# How do I reset deathmatch against bots after playing aim_botz?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

The aim_botz map screws with a bunch of cvars. That's fine, but after aim_botz, I want to play a quick deathmatch against moving, shooting targets. When I choose deathmatch offline against bots, there are a few things wrong:

- I cannot choose CT.
- I am the only terrorist.
- The game continues after the timer ends.

What settings do I need to change to get a normal deathmatch game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/filedetails/discussion/243702660/530646080845617098/) of that map tells you how to do this:

The command(s) `bot_join_team any; game_type 1;game_mode 1; mp_ignore_round_win_conditions 0; exec gamemode_competitive` in your console should fix it.

Alternatively just restart the game. This always loads the default config.

Then, you can use `bot_quota <amount_of_bots>` or `bot_add_<ct/t>` to add more bots, if necessary.